# How to put a title and the chapter number between two lines?

Tags: titlesec

[image]How can I put the chapter number and its name between two lines automatically for all the chapters I have?

Comment: This can be done with the `titlesec` package.

Comment: I need to do it as shown in the image but the chapter number always appears outside the two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large}
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}{0em}{\raggedleft Cap\'itulo \thechapter\\[2em]
 \Huge#1\\[-0.5em] \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}    

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introducci\'on}

 Bla
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!
it's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @MaxMeneses You are welcome!